# Lay out two triggers in different tables

Tags: mysql, trigger

So I have two `BEFORE INSERT` triggers. One is:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER Carperperson  /* This Trigger Blocks a customer from renting two cars on the same name twice on one day. */
BEFORE INSERT ON bookings   /*E.g. Mr.ABC cannot rent a Ford and a Nissan on the same day. Has to return first car first.[WORKING]*/
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM bookings 
    WHERE NEW.customer_id = bookings.customer_id
      AND ((new.start_date >= bookings.start_date 
            and new.start_date < bookings.end_date)
        or (new.end_date > bookings.start_date 
            and new.end_date < bookings.end_date))
) THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' 
        set message_text='You can only book one car per single customer a day!' ; /* This triggers only allows to rent a car for 7 days, not more, not less[WORKING]*/
END IF;
IF ( NEW.end_date > NEW.start_date + INTERVAL 7 DAY ) THEN
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
         SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'error end_date more than seven days after start_date'; 
   END IF;   
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

The other one is:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `check_repair` BEFORE INSERT ON `bookings` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    # We need to save the "count"
    DECLARE inspections_count INT DEFAULT 0;

    # Check if where is a repair going which matches the vehicle_id
    SELECT
      1 INTO inspections_count # store the "count" into the variable.
    FROM inspections
    WHERE
        inspections.vehicle_id = NEW.vehicle_id
      AND
        repair_complete = 'No'
    ORDER BY 
     inspections.start_date DESC
   LIMIT 1

    # if there is a "count" stop the insert.
    IF inspections_count = 0 THEN 
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
      SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'vehicle is in repair';
    END IF;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

They are both `BEFORE INSERT`, however they are for different tables. Do I need to create a new statement? How do you put the triggers so they load in properly?  What is the proper syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ["23.3.1 Trigger Syntax and Examples"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html):

> As of MySQL 5.7.2, it is possible to define multiple triggers for a given table that have the same trigger event and action time. For example, you can have two `BEFORE UPDATE` triggers for a table. By default, triggers that have the same trigger event and action time activate in the order they were created. To affect trigger order, specify a clause after `FOR EACH ROW` that indicates `FOLLOWS` or `PRECEDES` and the name of an existing trigger that also has the same trigger event and action time. With `FOLLOWS`, the new trigger activates after the existing trigger. With `PRECEDES`, the new trigger activates before the existing trigger.

So you can put more than one trigger for the same event for the same time on the same table without a problem, i.e., what you have should work (if you add a semicolon (`;`) after the `LIMIT 1` in the `check_repair` trigger (and maybe other errors I didn't spot)).

If the order in which the triggers fire doesn't matter, you're good as they are.

If it does however I'd recommend to define it as documented with `FOLLOWS` or `PRECEDES` as the order in which the triggers are created is prone to changes for example if you want to changes something in the one created first by dropping and recreating it, it suddenly and unwillingly is the last one. You'd always have to make sure the order of creation is kept, which is easy to forget.

In your case you might also go with unifying both triggers into one and order the statements in the order you like them to execute.

BTW: In your second trigger you could also use `IF EXISTS ...` like in the first one instead of the detour with the variable. That's probably easier to understand on the first glance.